# Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused

Tags: java, derby

i am create a java project and i want to use derby data base and and i am configured database and create database with the name of `/home/user/TestDB` and create a table `user` and insert 3 to 4 values into it and write a code to get the data from database but when i connect dada base i got connection refuse error, i am use

```
 DB URL : jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/home/user/TestDB
```

error logs :

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at test.derby.util.DerbyUtil.getConnecation(DerbyUtil.java:34)
    at test.derby.dao.TestDAO.getData(TestDAO.java:20)
    at test.derby.dao.TestDAO.main(TestDAO.java:39)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetAgent.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.newAgent_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl40.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
```

Comment: Nothing was listening at localhost on port 1527.

Answer (score 8):

i think you are not start your `derver server` in specific port which you are using. you need to start server using below command on localhost with default port `1527`

```
startNetworkServer -h 0.0.0.0
```

if you want to change the port you can use below command :

```
startNetworkServer -p 3301  // new port number
```

for more you can refer below link;

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheDerby/article.html

may be this error occur because of following reasons:

1) Firewall is not permitted for host-port combination

2) Client and Server, either or both of them are not in the network.

3) The server is running but not listening on the port, a client is trying to connect.

4) Server is not running.

5) Incorrect protocol in Connection String

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs just because your database is not connected.

**NETBEANS**

Go to Services>Database>Java DB>(right click)
After that simply right click on your database and connect database.

Answer (score 0):

**Best Solution**

**To execute the database program**

**Step 1:**
   First database server needs to be started

Open a command shell and change to a directory that will hold the database

files(in this following example the database going to stored in

D:\java2019\Database)

D:\java2019\Database>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\db\bin\startNetworkServer“

Wed Mar 13 10:36:36 IST 2019 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Wed Mar 13 10:36:37 IST 2019 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.11.1.2 - (1629631) started and ready to accept connections on   port 1527

The default port number is 1527 we can also change the port number by the following
cmd

D:\java2019\Database>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\db\bin\startNetworkServer" -p  1567

Wed Mar 13 10:46:33 IST 2019 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Wed Mar 13 10:46:33 IST 2019 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.11.1.2 - (1629631) started and ready to accept connections on port 1567

**Step2:**
compile and execute the java program

Open another command shell and change to a directory that will hold the database files. set the classpath for derbyrun.jar

set classpath=".;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\db\lib\derbyrun.jar”

**Step3:**
Finally the database server needs to be stopped

Open another command shell and change

D:\java2019\Database>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\db\bin\stopNetworkServer"
Wed Mar 13 10:56:04 IST 2019 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.11.1.2 - (1629631) shutdown