# Connection to a derby database in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, derby

i need to build a derby database connection using eclipse.Here's my code-

```
'String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
 String dbName="jdbcDemoDB";
// define the Derby connection URL to use 
String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/" + dbName+";create=true";
Connection conn = null;'
try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);       
        System.out.println("Connected to database " + dbName);
        s = conn.createStatement();
}
catch (Throwable e)  {   
        /*       Catch all exceptions and pass them to 
         *       the Throwable.printStackTrace method  */
        System.out.println(" . . . exception thrown:");
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
     }
```

I get an exception from the code (conn=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL)):

```
`java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at com.sid.WwdClientExample.main(WwdClientExample.java:57)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetAgent.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.newAgent_(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)'
```

I have included the derby jar files in my WEB-INF/lib folder.
I'm new to derby and i wanted to try to build a connection to derby.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using derby database with a web application?

Comment: Yes, I built a new web project wherein I added the derby jars and my java files.

Comment: Try adding this code before connection: `String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"; Class.forName(driver);`. Also verify what derby jar file you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I think I missed to add the code in the comment but I have added it in my file and how do i know which jar file to use??

Comment: I think this issue is same as the following post: [Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768537/error-connecting-to-server-localhost-on-port-1527-with-message-connection-refuse)

Comment: I want to ask you some more questions, Can I??

Comment: [Apache Derby user manuals](https://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/) (1) Getting Started with Derby -and- (2) Derby Server and Administration Guide has the details to setup and use the database in Network-Server (a.k.a. Server) mode.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I got it started. I wanted to know if there is any difference when starting derby as an environment or the embedded version other than the fact that in embedded version the db can be used by only one resource?

Comment: One can use Derby with a web  application using the embedded mode.

Comment: Thank you for your time.